# Instant ACH verification using a static site & some back end service

Tags: heroku, stripe-payments, github-pages, paas, plaid

Are there any remotely close open source back-end projects similar to the [GitHub flatmarket server Heroku deployment](https://mericsson.com/stripe-and-github-pages/) that work similarly for a generic [Stripe custom form + Plaid Link ACH transactions](https://stripe.com/docs/ach#manually-collecting-and-verifying-bank-accounts) for a static site?